# May I install Grid and Oracle DB on one (local) machine (Windows 10)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-rac, oracle19c

I want try to use FAN (Fast Application Notification) in Java Application. I found, that FAN cannot work without Grid and / or RAC. I found a lot of answers, how I can install Grid and RAC on multiple machines (clusters). But I didn't find nothing, how I can install Grid and Oracle Database (in my situation 19c) on same machine right. Is it possible?

I tried to install Grid with DB on my machine already. But I have problems with Listener. Because I have 2 ORACLE_HOME (one for Grid and second for DB).

Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: yes its possible. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ssdbi/installing-and-configuring-oracle-grid-infrastructure-for-a-standalone-server.html#GUID-DA3B90BE-EE1F-4347-8A5E-ED1BBFF29D93 , listener is running under GridHome

Comment: for windows: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/installing-oracle-restart-for-an-existing-database.html#GUID-30328B1C-7DCE-4D5A-B921-66BFC98B3756

Comment: @MarcelS Thank you for links! I'm trying it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your listener goes, one single listener, running from one single oracle home, is quite capable of - indeed, WAS DESIGNED FOR - handling multiple databases of multiple versions running from multiple homes.  In the case of a grid infrastructure environment - both the grid home and the separate database home on one server, the listener should be running from the grid home.  You do not need (or want) a listener for every home on the server, and you do not need (or want) a listener for every database on the server. The listener is just a switchboard, listening for incoming database connection requests, then servicing those requests regardless of which home a database is running from.